# C#/ Delegate does not have type parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

I have to two C# files:

1. `EventDel.cs`:

   ```cs
   public delegate void EventDel(DocdEvent event);
   ```
2. `HBE.cs` which contains the next field:

   ```cs
   public  EventDel<ME> toCatchOne {get; set; }
   ```

It gives me the next error:

```cs
Delegate does not have type parameters.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Remove the `<ME>` so it says `public EventDel toCatchOne {get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate does not appear to be generic, try this inside HBE.cs:

```
public  EventDel toCatchOne {get; set; }
```

Or this inside EventDel.cs:

```
public delegate void EventDel<HBE>(DocdEvent event);
```

Answer (score 0):

`EventDel` and `EventDel<T>` are two entierly different types. They are not compatible. In your case `EventDel` only accepts one parameter of type `DocdEvent`. And the type `EventDel<ME>` only accepts a parameter of type `ME` (whatever that is).

To make your code work, try:

```
public  EventDel<ME> toCatchOne {get; set; }
```

has to be converted into:

```
public  EventDel toCatchOne {get; set; }
```

Or modify your first delegate:

```
public delegate void EventDel(DocdEvent event);
```

into:

```
public delegate void EventDel(ME event);
```

In the last case, you are still using two different type of delegates, but if you want to convert one delegate into another, use the constructor:

```
EventDel d1 = ...;
EventDel<ME> d2 = new EventDel<ME>(d1);
```